# Issue scrolling down selectInput within a draggable absolute pane

Tags: r, shiny

When I run the App below I can't scroll down the dropdown menu using the scrolling bar on the right side because it causes the the dropdown menu to immediately disappear. I can only scroll down using the scroll wheel of the mouse. The problem does not exist if I am not in a draggable panel.

I need to be in a draggable panel and I don't want people using my app to get frustrated with this scroll down menu.

Anybody has an idea on how fix the problem?

Thanks a lot!

I am using version 1.0.5 of package Shiny. The problem occurs both in the viewer panel (RStudio version 1.1.442, R version 3.4.4) and when the app is run external on Google Chrome (version 67.0.3396.99).

Here is the code for the App.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- absolutePanel( id = "controls", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,
           draggable = TRUE, top = 60, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
           width = 500, height = "auto",

           uiOutput( 'color' )          
)

server <-   function( input, output, session ) {
output$color <- renderUI( selectInput(  inputId = "color", label = h4( "Variable" ), 
                                        selectize = TRUE, choices = LETTERS, 
                                        # selectize = TRUE, choices = varLst[[ input$varType ]][[ input$measType ]],
                                        selected = 'A') )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution consists in setting `draggable=FALSE` and wrapping the `absolutePanel` inside a `jqui_draggable` provided by the `shinyjqui` package, with the option `cancel = ".selectize-control"`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)
ui <- jqui_draggable(
  absolutePanel( id = "controls", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = FALSE,
                 draggable = FALSE, top = 60, left = "auto", right = 20, 
                 bottom = "auto", width = 500, height = "auto",
                 uiOutput( 'color' )
  ),
  options = list(cancel = ".selectize-control"))
```